# Checking the correctness of the adjacency matrix for the given graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I found the adjacency matrix for this graph; it is shown next to it. Is it correct?

[image]  [image]

Comment: Your adjacency matrix is correct.

Comment: so , do you have a program to this or right it by hand . if you have a program  just send the name of it please

Comment: First, you should rephrase your question so it's clear whether it's the adjacency matrix you want from the graph, or the graph you want from the adjacency matrix. Either way, I did it by hand: if you're confused about how to get the matrix, consider what the definition is.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to write a program to draw a graph from an arbitrary (symmetric) adjacency matrix anyway.

Comment: thank you @Alqatrkapa .  i just want to konw if is that true . but i see a program on net can draw this maybe (GraphMatrixGenerator) try it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the matrix is correct. As a side observation, the adjacency matrix being of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & * \\ * & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
tells us that we have a [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) (or rather multigraph, since you allow multiple edges).